# Why am I getting 400 bad error if I put 1 into page? and it won't fetch more than 25 results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the gem called [youtube search](https://github.com/grosser/youtube_search)

I coded like this below works fine. But it returns 400 Bad error when I type **1** into page like this

```
<% option = {
  :per_page => "10",
  :page     => 1,
}
%>
```

How can I fix this code to display first page of the result?

Then why it always show **25** when trying to show the number of matches that contains "cats" as the keyword?
It should be more than 10000 matches :(

```
# coding: utf-8


<% keyword = "cats" %>
<% option = {
  :per_page => "10",
  :page     => 2,
}
%>

<% videos = YoutubeSearch::search(keyword, option) %>

Video Count<%= YoutubeSearch::search(keyword).count %>


--------------------------------<br />
<br />

<% videos.each do |video| %>

Video ID:<%= video["video_id"] %> <br />
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= video["video_id"] %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> <br />
  Title: <%= video["title"] %><br />
  Content: <%= video["content"] %><br />
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />
  <br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That gem is, unfortunately, based on the now-retired V2 YouTube API ... you'll get intermittent results for the next few weeks (with, very likely, oddities like you're seeing here), and then it will be shut down completely at the end of the month. You'll want to switch your code to use V3 of the API (there's a client library [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/apis/youtube/v3) if you're interested in looking at it).